# Attaching Tinymce to dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to attach tinyMCE editor to dynamically added div. I am using the following code:

```
$('#btnModAddChapter').bind('click', function(){

    // add dynamic div for editor
    var divEditor = "<div id='editor_2' class='editor'>";
    divEditor += "</div>";

    $('#cont').append(divEditor);

    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "editor_2");
});
```

But it does not attach tinyMCE editor to the dynamically added div. So, to achieve this I have added the following code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.editor', function(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.editor',
        theme: 'modern',
        menubar: 'edit insert view table tools',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
          'save table contextmenu directionality template paste jbimages textcolor'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'fontselect | fontsizeselect | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent',
        toolbar2: 'link image jbimages print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons paste',
        inline: true,
        statusbar: false,
        relative_urls: false,
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom"
    });
})
```

The second approach works but it is repeatedly getting called whenever I mouseover the div element. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ID, through adding your TinyMCE initiate code inside your dynamic loop..

or can count number of textarea and app id using jquery each function